# How to use API using http package in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, http-headers

Im trying to use an API to remove background of an image. Therefore, I am using http flutter package. But I am getting `<title>400 Bad Request</title>` error. How can I fix this?

This is what i tried,

```
  removeBackGround(String imagePath) async {
    
    final body = {"image_file": imagePath};
    final headers = {"X-API-Key": "e5adebcdc77**************"};
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("https://sdk.photoroom.com/v1/segment"),
        body: body,
        headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response  ok");
      
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to do network requests: Error Code: ${response.statusCode}\nBody: ${response.body}');
    }
  }
```

this is the error

```
E/flutter (14230): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to do network requests: Error Code: 400
E/flutter (14230): Body: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
E/flutter (14230): <title>400 Bad Request</title>
E/flutter (14230): <h1>Bad Request</h1>
E/flutter (14230): <p>Could not decode image, ensure image_file or image_file_b64 is set</p>
```

Comment: "Could not decode image, ensure image_file or image_file_b64 is set" have you tried converting the image into base64? Or to convert into a File object? You're just passing a path

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I just passed File directly instead of the path and I am getting this error now Error - '[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast'

Comment: No! @MarianoZorrilla  you can upload an image from the path too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the post method slightly in a different  way, by using **MulipartFormRequest**

```
Future removeBackGround(imagePath) async {
  var request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'POST', Uri.parse("https://sdk.photoroom.com/v1/segment"));
  await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
    'image',
    imagePath,
    filename: 'image_$name.jpg',
  );
  // request.fields['companyName'] = name;
  // request.fields['own_id'] = id;
  request.headers["X-API-Key"] = "e5adebcdc77**************";

  var res = await request.send();
  return res.statusCode;
}
```

Using this method you can upload an images and json data at once.

Comment: What should I use as$name? random name or the exact name of the image?  [image_$name.jpg]

Comment: It's completely up to you,  whatever  you want,

Comment: I use this just for demo purpose image_$name.jpg can give any name. Its better you Use baseName from imagepicker

Comment: Bro, I am still getting code 400 :(  Why is that? Please help me.

Comment: e5adebcdc77d62ee0dfc9553a3654365c6d60074  this is my API key. You can use that for test purpose and this is not my official API key, therefore, its fine

Comment: what are you using on the server side?

Comment: you are getting this error because it's a problem with your server?

Comment: I am using photoroom.com and I use that API key to remove a background of an image.

Comment: You should see how this function works with  backend using Nodejs  https://m-jan9396.medium.com/

Comment: Do you mean is that issue of a API provider ?

Comment: URL String Syntax Error. The HTTP error 400 can occur due to an incorrectly typed URL, malformed syntax, or a URL that contains illegal characters.  A 400 Bad Request error happens when a server cannot understand a request that’s been made of it. It’s called a 400 error because that’s the HTTP status code that the web server uses to describe that kind of error.

Comment: Bro To be honest I have no idea, How this is working. I ll put documentation link    Link - https://www.notion.so/API-Documentation-public-4eb3e45d9c814f92b6392b7fd0f1d51f

Comment: So, It is an issue of the API provider right ?

Comment: The problem is they want a binary image and you are try to send them an image file. so they couldn't  understand  what we send to them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233964/discussion-between-isuru-bandara-and-mehran-ullah).